# How do I get the username owning the currently active gui session?

Tags: linux, gnome, window-managers

I published [some scripts to automatically mount](https://github.com/fatso83/Code-Snippets/tree/master/system-utils/ubuntu/automount) and unmount disks in Linux, and now I got [a request](https://github.com/fatso83/Code-Snippets/issues/1#issuecomment-21483064) to make the disks owned by the currently logged in user. That is, the user currently holding the gui occupied (we don't care about terminal users in this case).

How would I go about getting hold of the username? There could be a multitude of different window managers, so different solutions depending on wm might be needed, if no wm-independant solution exists.

For a start, a solution just targeting Gnome might be enough.

**The script is running outside of any user session (triggered by udev).**

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a bash script, the username of the currently logged-in user should be stored as an environment variable, `$USER` or `$USERNAME`. The `env` command will give you a list of all environment variables in the current shell.

Now if you want the user id of the current user, use the `id` command.

Comment: I thought it was clear from the info that I was running these scripts outside of the gui session, but I guess not :) Added info on that now.

Comment: sorry about that. You _might_ be able to find the user id running one of the processes associated with the gui, say the X server or one of the window manager's processes, in the foreground at the time of the scripts execution and use that information to mount the disks, but I cannot say that I have ever tried this and I foresee possible portability issues. Good Luck with your script.

Comment: Thanks. Grepping the output from ps is the only cross-gui solution I can see atm.

Answer (score 1):

`w -hs | grep tty7 | cut -f1 -d ' '` seems to work if your xserver is attached to `tty7` (modify accordingly).

Answer (score 0):

Gnome should start an process called gdm (Gnome Display Manager).

If you grep for it, it should pass you the user who is running it.

```
ps aux | grep gdm
```